# Why does Mysql query only give me the last result of a query instead of all results?

Tags: php, mysql

getting values

```
session_start();
$text = $_SESSION['text']; (it's an array with multiple values)
```

making the array suitable for the query

```
$text = array_filter($text);
$text = implode("','", $text);
$text = "'".$text."'";
```

run query

```
$sql = "SELECT id_category FROM eiofm_category_lang WHERE name IN (".$text.")";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

get query result

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    var_dump($result);
}
```

EDIT

I got it working with a foreach loop but still don't know why the while loop didn't work.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: First check how many rows are being retrieved from the database. $sql = "SELECT id_category FROM eiofm_category_lang WHERE name IN (".$text.")"; $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // Check if there's any SQL error message $result = mysql_fetch_array($query); //$result have array echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); // Check your $result array. Let me know what you get here.

Comment: Have you checked what's in $text?

Comment: Can you please print your query with $text value here. So we can comes to know does $text having single value or multiple.

Comment: As far as I know, this $row will return an array with some fetched rows, not technically the "number" of rows. I don't recall the question being associated with the no of rows..it's about what the result array contains....Which is the first step of debugging.

Comment: Nope, this is not correct. $row will contain the values from exactly 1 row, or false if no rows match the query, or all have been returned already. But even if your code were accurate, this response is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Array([0] => 14[id_category] => 14), this is what I get when i run the query die($sql) and copy/paste the query to mysql it gives me 4 rows back, Yet when i run the script, it only gives me one result.

Comment: SELECT id_category FROM eiofm_category_lang WHERE name IN ('Dessert ','Gemengde dozen ',' ','Tussendoortjes ','Warme gerechten')

Comment: $text = array("Dessert","Gemengde dozen"," ","Tussendoortjes","Warme gerechten")

Comment: Joey- Please var_dump($text) and check its value before executing the query. @Shadow- It's obvious that while fetching data, it can return 0, 1 or multiple rows..not sure what you're getting at. And as far as the answer is concerned, we gotta debug it stepwise. That itself is the answer..

Comment: I get the right values when I var_dump($text) : string(68) "'Dessert ','Gemengde dozen ',' ','Tussendoortjes ','Warme gerechten'

Comment: No, you got it wrong on both accounts. It is okay to ask clarifications and debugging info from the OP in **comments**, but an answer is supposed to provide an explanation to question, not simply say: debug it. At the moment you do not know the answer to the question. mysql_fetch_array() cannot return more than 1 row. Pls read the php manual if you do not believe me. Since you do not call this function in a loop as the OP does, all you can get is a single row from the resultset. This is lso confirmed by the OP's comment above.

Comment: @Jens unfortunately this is not possible because it's a big project and I'm working in a script that's not made by me

Comment: @Shadow Can you show me how it's done properly?

Comment: @JoeySteenbergen Then you will get a problem in the future, because in actual php version these API is removed

Comment: @JoeySteenbergen I cannot. At the moment I cannot see any issue with your code. There are 2 things that come to my mind: 1) your query returns only 1 record for some reason. You need to debug it in your code using count(*) in the select list. 2) Sg is wrong with the way you output the results and you simply cannot see the other records in the output. Again, this is sg only you can check.

Comment: Could it be a case sensitive issue, or some of those trailing spaces? Run array_filter with trim. `array_filter($array, 'trim');`, but perhaps first, try and run the code without a WHERE clause to see if you do get multiple results.  Add a LIMIT if you have many rows.

Comment: array_filter($array, 'trim') did not work and yes I do get multiple rows back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
foreach($text as $values){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id_category FROM eiofm_category_lang WHERE link_rewrite LIKE '$values'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    array_push($array, $row['id_category']);
}}
```

But still don't know why the while loop didn't work